# Is it due to irregularity of geoid, we cannot convert the height between spherical datum and local datum by cs2cs?

Tags: coordinate-system, geoid

Is it due to irregularity of geoid, we cannot convert the height between spherical datum and local datum (which uses locally defined geoid and height) by cs2cs?

What I mean is that, by using cs2cs, it only accepts x and y / lat and lon as input. The z / height data is not accepted for the conversion program. Does it mean that z / height cannot be directed converted?

What if I convert between spherical data, can it be converted directly by using projection formula?

Comment: Please state tools, software, and more information about what and how you have tried.  Edit original question please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PROJ and cs2cs were mainly designed to convert between 2D datums. There was some effort to add vertical datums, but this has not gone very far:

http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/VerticalDatums

If you need height coordinates conversion, feel free to sponsor the development ;-)